# Rails/Mongoid accepting nested attributes for models with inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

How do you accept nested attributes for models that use inheritance?

Rails 3.2, Mongoid 3.1

```
class User
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps

    field :name, type: String

    attr_accessible :name

    embeds_many :cards
    attr_accessible :cards_attributes
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :cards

end
```

The user class embeds many types of cards.

```
class Card
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps

    embedded_in :user
end

class HealthCard < Card
    field :number,      type: String

    attr_accessible :expiry_date, :number
end

class StudentCard < Card
    field :expiry_date, type: Date
    field :number,      type: String
    field :dept,        type: String


    attr_accessible :expiry_date, :number, :dept
end
```

The form below is used

```
= form_for @user do |user_form|

    = user_form.fields_for :health_cards, @health_card do |hc_form|
        = hc_form.text_field :number

    = user_form.submit 'Next'
```

On submit I observe the following params

```
{"user"=>{"health_cards"=>{"number"=>"6564 - 082 - 649 - AM"} }, "utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"C0DIKNbccfDQ=", "commit"=>"Next", "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"person_steps"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the form, it should be `user_form.fields_for :cards` instead of `:health_cards`

Below is the corrected version

```
= form_for @user do |user_form|

    = user_form.fields_for :cards, @health_card do |hc_form|
        = hc_form.text_field :number

    = user_form.submit 'Next'
```

Comment: how to initiate 'user' with 'cards' attribute? @user.build_cards?